# Loading of GWT page/project taking more time in Edge browser than Chrome and Safari browsers

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, microsoft-edge

I am working on a GWT project, When I am launching my GWT project in Chrome/Safari browsers, it is taking some reasonable time in Chrome and Safari browsers but it is taking more time in Edge browser.

Can anyone please help or explain, is it Edge browser issue or GWt issue?.

Thanks in Advance!!
[image]

Comment: First thing would probably be to understand *what* takes time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/performance

Comment: At present, We don't know whats your GWT application is doing. From only description it is hard to tell the cause for the issue. You can try to develop an sample GWT app and try to test it with MS Edge and check how much time it takes. check whether it takes the same time as your actual app or it takes less time. further, Try to use developer tools in MS Edge to check the performance of your web app.

Answer (score 1):

Are you injecting a lot of DOM elements while the GWT page is loading ?

Injecting elements is A LOT slower in IE/Edge than in all other browsers.

Comment: Hi @Knarf, I checked in performance tab(Java Script call stacks) of edge browser, In the URL column showing a lot of DOM calls. is you are saying about this?

Comment: Added a screenshot!!

Comment: Try building up your UI in a single panel. Only add this panel to the browser DOM once it is completely finished. Thus giving you only one DOM injection.